# jQuery get the element of clicked class instead of every element with that class that is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="content content-1">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="new-content">new content </a>
</div>
<div class="content content-2">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="new-content">new content </a>
</div>
<div class="content content-3">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="new-content">new content </a>
</div>
```

How can I get the element of clicked class instead of every element with that class that is clicked?

Here's my jquery:

```
$('.new-content').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.content').find('.row').show(); 
}
```

This, however, selects all `.row` instead of the closest row of the clicked class

=======================Update (Sorry, I oversimplified wrongly)===========

```
<div class="content content-1">
    <div class="row">
        <h4> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="new-content">new content</a>             
        <h4>
    </div>
    <div class="new-answer">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content content-2">
    <div class="row">
        <h4> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="new-content">new content</a>             
        <h4>
    </div>
    <div class="new-answer">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content content-3">
    <div class="row">
        <h4> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="new-content">new content</a>             
        <h4>
    </div>
    <div class="new-answer">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select only one `.new-answer`of the clicked `.new-content`

Comment: apart from the class selectors it looks fine `$(this).closest('.content').find('.row').show();`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4tmfy9j3/1/

Comment: you can even shorten it to `$(this).prev('.row').show();` - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4tmfy9j3/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you will have the same html structure consistently:

```
$('.new-content').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.row').next().show(); 
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/oLmvcuwk/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.new-content').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.content').find('.new-answer').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just missed the `.`(dot) in the jquery selector (in `closest` and `find`), otherwise rest of your code will give you the desired result. Without `.` (dot), selector will look for `content` and `row` tag element instead of class of the element.

see this

```
$('.new-content').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.content').find('.row').show(); 
                     ^-------- dot ---^
}
```

**EDIT** - Answer after OP updated the question, please see below code where you can use `closest()` to get parent `row` div and then use `next()` to get new content.

```
$('.new-content').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').next('.new-answer').show(); 
}
```

OR

```
$('.new-content').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.content').find('.new-answer').show(); 
   }
```

Comment: if so how OP is saying `This, however, selects all .row instead of the closest row of the clicked class`

Comment: I don't think it was selecting until and unless there is any `content` and `row` tag inside DOM. see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4tmfy9j3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one `div` before your `.new-content` and that `div` is of class `.row` then below code will do the job too!!

```
$('.new-content').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('.row').show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, please use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in this case for the better DOM event binding and rendering performance. I have done one example at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/thangchung/4tmfy9j3/8/). Hope this help.

`$('.content a', $('#content-container')).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).prev('.row').show();
});`

Answer (score 0):

You have traverse to next div from target content . use code snippet.

```
    $('.new-content').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('div').next('div').show()
}
```

closest method select closest element from target and next method is selected element from the target element